# WebSockets-Sending image to Clients connected

Tags: html, websocket

This is my first post on stackoverflow.com so I will try to be straightforward.
I have to develop a functionality of an webapp using websockets.I am able to send text data 
using websockets,but not an image.I've looked and tryied different possibilies,but couldn't make it work.The processing of the image has to be in javascript.

Please help me if you have a solution.
Thanks.

Update : I've succeded to send an image with websockets using the FileReader Api of HTML5.
Thanks to everyone.

Comment: I use Jetty at server side,and on client side JavaScript.I don't want to do processing off the data sent on the server side,but on client side.

Comment: http://www.websocket.org/quantum.html this might help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Websockects can't send images or anything else than binary data. You can solve this by converting the image runtime to Base64 data and decoding it through javascript to an image.

There are a lot of examples of how to decode a Base64 encoded image, but you can also embed it in the image src directly: `<img src="data:image/png;base64,xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" />` where you replace the x'es with your Base64 data.