# HTML5 / Javascript - DataURL to Blob & Blob to DataURL

Tags: javascript, html, blob

I have a DataURL from a canvas that shows my webcam. I turn this dataURL into a blob using Matt's answer from here: [How to convert dataURL to file object in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6850276/how-to-convert-dataurl-to-file-object-in-javascript)

How do I convert this blob back into the same DataURL? I've spent a day researching this and I'm astouned this isn't documented better, unless I'm blind.

EDIT:
There is

```
var urlCreator = window.URL || window.webkitURL; 
var imageUrl = urlCreator.createObjectURL(blob);
```

but it only returns a really short URL that seems to point at a local file, but I need to send the webcam data over a network.

Comment: Or if someone knows of any other two methods to convert between DataURL and Blob, I'd be extremely grateful. It's nagging me.

Comment: Is it even possible to turn a URL into a blob, send the blob over a network and turn the blob into a URL again?

Do I have a thinking mistake?

Comment: Since my attempts at compressing the dataURL string and sending it that way seem to be failing too, I'll allow myself to bump this once more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nevermind, it ended up working after sticking to the instructions in this thread [Display image from blob using javascript and websockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11089732/display-image-from-blob-using-javascript-and-websockets) and making my server forward raw (yet) unmodified BinaryWebSocketFrames.

Now I'm still fighting bad performance of the canvas (<1fp) but that might become subject of a new thread.

Answer (score 115):

Use my code to convert between dataURL and blob object in javascript. (better than the code in your link.)

```
//**dataURL to blob**
function dataURLtoBlob(dataurl) {
    var arr = dataurl.split(','), mime = arr[0].match(/:(.*?);/)[1],
        bstr = atob(arr[1]), n = bstr.length, u8arr = new Uint8Array(n);
    while(n--){
        u8arr[n] = bstr.charCodeAt(n);
    }
    return new Blob([u8arr], {type:mime});
}

//**blob to dataURL**
function blobToDataURL(blob, callback) {
    var a = new FileReader();
    a.onload = function(e) {callback(e.target.result);}
    a.readAsDataURL(blob);
}

//test:
var blob = dataURLtoBlob('data:text/plain;base64,YWFhYWFhYQ==');
blobToDataURL(blob, function(dataurl){
    console.log(dataurl);
});
```

Comment: I think the thing that was not obvious to me about `FileReader ` is adding the `onload` event before you call `readAsDataURL`

Answer (score 18):

Here is a `Promise`-based Typescript version with proper error checking.

```js
function blobToDataURL(blob: Blob): Promise<string> {
  return new Promise<string>((resolve, reject) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = _e => resolve(reader.result as string);
    reader.onerror = _e => reject(reader.error);
    reader.onabort = _e => reject(new Error("Read aborted"));
    reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

DataURL to Blob has a better solution:

```
const dataURL = "dataURL string...";
const res = await fetch(dataURL);
const blob = await res.blob();
```

Comment: Nice and succint!

Answer (score 1):

I like one-liners, so here's a `Promise`-based one to convert a blob to a data URL:

```js
let blob = ...;
let dataUrl = await new Promise(r => {let a=new FileReader(); a.onload=r; a.readAsDataURL(blob)}).then(e => e.target.result);
```

Or, as a function:

```js
function blobToDataUrl(blob) {
  return new Promise(r => {let a=new FileReader(); a.onload=r; a.readAsDataURL(blob)}).then(e => e.target.result);
}

let dataUrl = await blobToDataUrl(blob);
```