# Why does this SVG-holding `blob:` URL taint the canvas in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, fabricjs

I'm doing to following:

1. Generate an SVG document as a string
2. Capture it in a `blob:` URL with `new Blob` and `createObjectURL`
3. Create a `fabric.Image` object from it using [`fromURL`](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Image.html#.fromURL)
4. In the `fromURL` callback, call `canvas.add` to add the new `Image` to the canvas

This is my code:

```
var svg = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="200" height = "200"><foreignObject width="100%" height="100%"><text xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style = "font-size: 40px; color: #FFFFFF">Example</text></foreignObject></svg>';
var svgBlob = new Blob([svg], {type: 'image/svg+xml'});
var svgURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(svgBlob);
 fabric.Image.fromURL(svgURL,function(oIMG) {
   oIMG.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
   canvas.add(oIMG);
 });
```

Then I try `getImageData:`

```
var dataImage = context.getImageData(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height).data;
```

In Chrome, this gives me the error:

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute
>   'getImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The canvas has been
>   tainted by cross-origin data.

This is strange because I don't ever use any cross-origin URLs, only `blob:` URLs.

In Firefox it works perfectly. The problem appears to be specific to Chrome.

Comment: Is the image hosted on a CORS friendly site? Also try changing `Anonymous` to `anonymous`.

Comment: I used anonymous and empty value, not working. What do you mean about CORS friendly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix getImageData() error The canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22097747/how-to-fix-getimagedata-error-the-canvas-has-been-tainted-by-cross-origin-data)

Comment: What is `oIMG`? If it's an `Image` object (i.e., an `<img>` DOM object), what is its `src` property?

Comment: @apsillers fabric.Image loads image from my url (generated by blob), and oIMG is new object after download image

Comment: @Amy what do you mean about possible duplicate? No one solution from your thread not working.

Comment: @CustomerExplorer it's a *possible* duplicate because it *appears* to be the same issue.  It probably appears to be the same issue because it is.

Comment: @Amy I don't think this is a duplicate of that, because this case does not load from an external URL, but instead uses a local `blob:` URL (so `crossOrigin` won't have any significance, I think?).

Comment: @apsillers console.log(oIMG) return <img crossorigin="anonymous" src="blob:https://....">

Comment: @apsillers, thank you for editing my topic. It's very nice!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a known bug in Chrome: [Canvas is tainted after drawing SVG including <foreignObject>](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=294129). The current workaround is noted in that thread:

> It seems that in the meantime the canvas is not tainted if the same picture has been loaded from a data URI.
>
> This provides for a workaround.

You can [turn your blob into a `data:` URL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30407959/710446) via `FileReader` like so:

```
var svg = '...';
var svgBlob = new Blob([svg], {type: 'image/svg+xml'});

var reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsDataURL(svgBlob);

reader.onload = function(e) {
    var svgDataURL = e.target.result;
    fabric.Image.fromURL(svgDataURL, function(oIMG) {
        canvas.add(oIMG);
    });
}
```

Comment: Still a bug 285 days later. Thanks for the workaround!