# How to convert blob to .png file in javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, blob

I want to convert a blob file to a png. I tried this:

```
var blob = new Blob([ia], {type: 'image/png'});
$scope.farmerRegisterObj.farmerImage = blob;
```

I want to convert it into file object ..and should be able to append in a Formdata.

Comment: Here's another similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7651373/841804

Comment: or may be this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11089732/display-image-from-blob-using-javascript-and-websockets

Comment: A Blob is a File like object, or more exactly, a File is a Blob with a name. You can create a File object from a Blob thanks to the File constructor (check browser support), but this will be useless in almost every use cases. All you can do with a File can be done with a Blob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Blob) is a File like object, or more exactly, a [File object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/File) is a Blob with a `name` property.

You can create a File object from a Blob thanks to the `File(blob, name)` constructor, but this will be useless in almost every use cases*.

**All you can do with a File can be done with a Blob.**

For instance, in your case, you can append a Blob directly into a FormData so that it is sent as a file/multipart :

```
var form = new FormData();
form.append(fieldName, blob, fileName);
```

---

<sub>* I only used it once, while trying to hack the behavior of browsers default page title when viewing a file like an image in a tab, and it only partially worked only in FF. If someone has real use cases where a File is needed, I'd be glad to know about it.</sub>